# How to configure an Apache rewrite-rule to redirect all requests to 404 unless explicitly allowed

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I'm searchin on internet since yesterday and i couldn't find the answer. At least one that works for apache2.

I just want a set of rewritemod rules that will make apache redirect everything to a 404 but allows me to explicitly override it for some files/folders.

I've tried an inclusive rule but i couldn't get it working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just try this line in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!(allowedFile\.html|allowedDirectory/)) - [R=404,L,NC]
```

Above rule will throw 404 for everything except a file called `allowedFile.html` and a folder called `allowedDirectory`.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^/protectedfolder/(.*) -  [L] /* no substitution , serve as it is for this folder*/
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404,L] /*reject everything */
```

Comment: thanks man, but it doesn't work as expected. I want to redirect everything to 404, even 403(forbidden) errors. I've tried to use a rewritecond like this: 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images' also, and a simple rule to redirect everything, but it doesn't work.